# Get Type of User or Group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, groups

I have a case where in I have added AD security groups along with SharePoint Users to the SharePoint Groups, Now I want to fetch a list of only Security Groups from all Site Groups in SharePoint, Is it possible through powershell or Console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Script will get all the security groups listed in your groups at web level,similarly you can get if principal is Distribution list or a user or a Sharepoint Group

POWERSHELL

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
       Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
Write-Output "Starting process"
$outArray = @()
$websites = Get-SPWeb "http://site/*" 


foreach($web in $websites)
{
    $groups = $web.Groups

    foreach($grp in $groups)
    {
        $reachedMax= $false
        $principalInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::GetPrincipalsInGroup($web,$grp.Name,1000,[ref]$reachedMax)
        if($principalInfo.Count -gt 0)
        {
         foreach($info in $principalInfo)
         {
           if($info.PrincipalType -eq "SecurityGroup")
           {
              $outObject="" | select "Web","Group","SecurityGroup"
              $outObject.Web=  "Site Name and URL : " + $web.Title + " : " + $web.Url + ","
               $outObject.Group = $grp.Name+","
              $outObject.SecurityGroup += $outObject.SecurityGroup + " " + $info.DisplayName
               $outArray += $OutObject
              $outObject=$null
           }
         }     
       }
     }
 }
    $outArray | export-csv "c:\myFolder\FileName.csv"
Write-Output "finished process"
```